# Expand and Collapse a UIView within a UIViewController

Tags: ios, ios5

I want to expand a view on click of a button and collapse the same.And accordingly change the frame of the data residing below the view. I have used a scrollview and then added the items to scroll.

[image]

[image]

I am able to add  a new view and hide it initially and on click of (+) button I unhide that view,and hide the (+)button.

Two concerns

1) How do I manage the data below the view so the when the view is in collapse position the data should be just below the view? And when I expand it it should change the frame accordingly.
2) The label "The label is test1" is a single label. I would be showing the description there. Initially 4 lines and when we click (+) button the remaining description would be shown.So this would not be possible if I take another view as I need to take a single label or text view to display data.

```
-(IBAction)plusButton:(id)sender{

    [plusButton setHidden:YES];
    [expandedView setHidden:NO];

    //[mainView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 150, 294, 400)];

}

-(IBAction)minusButton:(id)sender{
    [plusButton setHidden:NO];
    [expandedView setHidden:YES];

}
```

Comment: It depends, how are you doing the animation to bring the window down? I'd suggest using [UIView animationWithDuration: animation: completion:] block because you can control it more efficiently, but decscribe how you're doing it

Comment: i am just hiding and unhiding the view the main concern is i cannot take a single label if a take two view's.

Comment: u can set frame of view by putting it under animation code and need to change y position of bottom label along with frame height of content label.

Comment: @Herçules : But there i am using two view so how can i display the data on single label and use it on both views. ??

Comment: u need to use two view . u can handle it by single view

Comment: @Herçules : Yeah but can you give me a demo.I can't hide a part of view and unhide it. m i right ??

Comment: just slide the one view down, create a variable to hold the content of one of the items you are updating/editing, and then replace the old data with the new. Check out @rezand's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use animation something like that

whether it is UIView or UIlabel use anyone of them..

connect containerView outlet to contact Info label or view. and bottom view outlet to label containing "lorel ipsum... "

```
//on plus button click

IBOutlet UILabel *containerView;
IBOutlet UILabel *bottomView;

CGRect rect=containerView.frame;
rect.size.height=400;

CGRect rect2=bottomView.frame;
rect2.origin.y=420;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
   [containerView setFrame:rect];
    [bottomView setFrame:rect2];
}];


//on minus button click


CGRect rect=containerView.frame;
rect.size.height=300;

CGRect rect2=bottomView.frame;
rect2.origin.y=320;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    [containerView setFrame:rect];
    [bottomView setFrame:rect2];
}];
```

Comment: Hercules : the animation works perfectly but when i click anywhere on screen it comes to it original position.Also i need to have the same label in which half of the data is shown when the view is not expanded and the continuing remaining data when the view is expanded

Comment: because it is on scroll view. On clicking scroll view it calls didScroll and comes back to original position

Comment: Probably, but we need a scrollview altogether and what about the label thing.

Comment: Label or view whatever u r using.I m not telling u to remove that.Just find out some alternative.

Comment: HerCules : Yeah.. but i am not getting fix in my brain as of now please help.Sending you a demo copy as well.

Comment: Ok I'll check when getting switched to mac

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like an autoresizing issue.
You need to set the label's and textfields  autoresizing to

UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight and UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin

I would suggest you place those labels and textfields in a "content" view with the same autoresizing properties and add that as a subview as well.

edit: (added example)

```
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; //contentView's initail frame.
UILabel *descriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentView.bounds]; //in this example the label takes the whole frame of the contentView, you can change it to be smaller in height if it suits you purpose.

descriptionLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

on "+" button clicked:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
    CGRect rect = contentView.frame;
    rect.size.height = 200;
    contentView.frame = rect;
}];
```

on "-" button clicked:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
    CGRect rect = contentView.frame;
    rect.size.height = 100;
    contentView.frame = rect;
}];
```

Comment: Lirik : It would be great if you give me some links displaying the above example, so that my concept is cleared.

Comment: added example in original answer

Comment: Lirik : Friend, I have used your code above one in VDl and the remaining in respective + and - button.But it does not reflect any change. Probably it is the same thing what Rezald was doing so i must tell you i have a scrollview and then the items added to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can animate a view in and out of screen using a animation block like this, this is a example taken from one of my apps moving a view within a view resulting in a slide up from the bottom effect.

```
  -(void) showFxAnimation {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.65];
     [self.sliderFxSubView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 150,320.0f , 150.0f)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];    
}


-(void) hideFxAnimation {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

        [self.sliderFxSubView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 1200.0f, 320.0f, 150.0f)];

    }];

}
```

Comment: Rezand :sliderFxSubview is the second view to be shown ??? If so then i added the above code to (+) and (-) button respectively but it does not reflect any change.

Comment: are you still using a scrollview?

Comment: Rezand : Yes and i believe we need to use it as we don't know what amount of data the label would be holding and how large the height of View would be .

Comment: ok. still should be some effect, i guess ill test this out in a scrollview myself now.

Comment: Rezand : I am afraid it does not. Yeah That would be great if you need i can send you a demo copy ASAP so that you can make changes at a fast pace.

Comment: Rezand : I will do that.